# Execute cmd in scala with space char in s3 path

Tags: scala, amazon-s3

I wish to execute shell cmds in scala, using the following

```
def executeShellCommand(cmd: String): Unit = {
   if (cmd.! != 0) {
     throw new RuntimeException(s"Error executing command '$cmd'")
   }
}
```

I receive a cmd such as the following, which contains a space in the s3 path (From Sender)

```
"aws s3 cp s3://external-bucket/From Sender/my-file.txt s3://my-bucket/my-file.txt"
```

Unfortunately, I get an error when running this cmd.

I believe if I could transform this to a sequence, the cmd would work correctly

```
Seq("aws", "s3", "cp", "s3://external-bucket/From Sender/my-file.txt", "s3://my-bucket/dataset/my-file.txt").!
```

The cmd string comes from an external source, so I cannot easily transform it to a sequence.  I have tried enclosing the s3 bucket path in quotes, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas how I can run this cmd in scala?

Comment: Are you sure that it's your job to fix the command? It appears to me that the service which gives you the commands should make sure that they are valid.

Comment: Can you modify the cmd string, by quoting the files, for instance? If you can do that, it should be easy to transform into a sequence

Comment: It's a good point, that the supplier of the cmd is sending one which is incorrect.  Still, it would be nice if the framework would handle the case of the s3 path in escaped quotes

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason shell cannot execute that command for you is because it doesn't know how to split it into arguments. So, unless you have any additional information about the command, that you could use to fix it, you are out of luck.

If you do have additional info, you could try and fix it, but YMMV. For example, if you know that the argument list is always a bunch of s3 paths, you could do something like this:

```
 cmd.split("(?=s3://)").flatMap { 
   case x if x.startsWith("s3://") => Seq(x.trim) 
   case x => x.split(" ")
 }.toSeq.!
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I've found that enclosing the path in quotes doesn't work.  The only solution I'm aware of is splitting into a sequence

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just realized that. I updated the answer to show how you can split it.